# Where outside of Crimea can I experience Crimean Tatar culture?

Tags: europe, safety, where-on-earth, culture, crimea

Where can I safely experience Crimean Tatar culture?

Smartraveller gives the Crimean region a [do not travel](https://smartraveller.gov.au/countries/ukraine) rating, the worst safety rating possible. Are there parts of Ukraine, or other countries, that are (at least somewhat) safe to travel to and where I can experience Crimean Tatar culture?

Comment: Turkey, Uzbekistan, Romania. This may help - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Tatar_diaspora . Also see the chart to the right of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Tatars . Back when I lived in Uzbekistan (a long time ago, still in Soviet times, as a kid), I do remember Crimean Tatars occasionally being mentioned, but I don't know how much of a distinct culture they maintained, especially outwardly-visible distinct culture, I was way too young to notice such things.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any unusual safety issue in traveling to Crimea as opposed to Eastern Ukraine (entering through Russia, of course), but there may be other issues (such as breaking Ukrainian law).

Comment: Millions of Russians visited Crimea in 2015 and millions more will visit in 2016. The whole "Do not travel" thing is nonsense.

Comment: Also, could you define what "experience" amounts to?

Comment: @JonathanReez they are Russians they are used to  "extreme" treatment. But if op can overcome stuff that will make most of western tourists run away in panic he can travel there for sure.

Comment: http://bestwestern-sevastopol.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to simply go to Crimea, despite what travel websites might say. Crimea currently has no active warzones or civil unrest, so the likelihood of getting into trouble shouldn't be any higher than anywhere else in Russia. Just because a territory is internationally disputed doesn't mean it's in the middle of active warfare.

[Four million tourists](https://www.google.cz/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=millions%20of%20visitors%20crimea&oq=millions%20of%20visitors%20crimea&aqs=chrome..69i57.4943j0j1) visited Crimea in 2015 and there have been zero reports of conflict-related deaths/casualties, so you should be fine.