# How would I find a reliable attorney in Russia to assist me in case consular support is unavailable?

Tags: legal, russia

In [What are the practical implications of limited consular support in Russia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175531/what-are-the-practical-implications-of-limited-consular-support-in-russia) @Danubian writes:

> So if you want to go anyway, you should at least make sure you have any local contact that would be able to provide you financial and legal help (at least in form of translation service) in cause you get into trouble.

I'm going to Russia in September to spend a week in Moscow. How do I find a lawyer in advance to help me out in case of any legal issues? Is there an official government website listing lawyers specializing in working with foreigners?

NB: I am **not** asking for contacts of specific Russian lawyers. I'm just asking for a way to find one, similar to [How do I find an immigration lawyer/solicitor to help with my UK Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio)

Comment: The embassy (of your respective country/countries) may have a list, either published or available upon request.

Comment: Have you tried google?   Because it looks like you are asking a shopping question.

Comment: Through **recommendation** from others who have used a specific lawyer in the past is often the best way to determine the reliablity/quality of a lawyer. This is, hopefully, what a consulate does with their lists. In Moscow itself, consular support should be available. It is outside of Moscow where problems with availablity may arise.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The consulate is only available to the extent it exists and is staffed.

Comment: @littleadv Yes, but since I don't know the citizenship of the OP that cannot be determined. For Germany, the UK and US they are.

Comment: For the US, at least, they're not actually staffed well. There are currently 3 consulates (one at the embassy and two separate) for the US in Russia, and the one in Moscow is now solely responsible for the most populous and most touristic areas.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Of course even if you know a suitable lawyer, they may still decline to take your case.

Comment: This question needs more clarity. OP wants a government list but fails to mention what government (UK? US? etc.?) The US state department clearly states that American citizens should not travel to Russia whatsoever.